# can i install an outlet here?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

i would like to place a receptacle outside my house. i have found a couple of this two black and green wires on the wall. i was wondering if there is the possibility of wiring a receptacle here. it is worth noting that this is outside.[image] any thought as to what this may be?
as always thank you

Comment: Where are you in the world? 2 blacks in the us would normally be 240v  someone may have pulled in the wires for a air conditioning unit and you would not have a neutral. I would measure the voltage or find the breaker that controls this if still connected in the service panel.

Comment: 2 blacks may also have been for a switch. But regardless, and more importantly, Green usually means Ground, and you CANNOT use a ground wire in lieu of a Neutral wire.